# Bootstrap3 whitespace below footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace, footer

[Here](http://lcc-web.ru/modus/) you can clearly see a blank space that comes after the footer and it seems to be equal to the background-color of the body tag.

How can I get rid of that?

Thank you.

EDIT

OK, so provided solutions have done the job so far, but [I've got another one here](http://lcc-web.ru/art/). Just one block and a white space under, can't get what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main css file and add these changes.

```
.footer-bottom {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    background-color: #6ab3ac;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
.footer-bottom {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        background-color: #6ab3ac;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #fff;
    }
```